# Ejecutar sentencias por un periodo de tiempo

Tags: javascript

Quiero que se la sentencia `console.log('ejecutando');` se ejecute repetidas veces durante un tiempo determinado. Al culminar ese intervalo, habiendo seteado la bandera en `false`, la ejecución debería culminar.

Mi solución no funciona. ¿Por qué?

```js
var bandera = true;
setTimeout(function () {
    bandera = false;
}, 60000);

while (bandera ) {
   console.log('ejecutando');
}
```

Comment: Me pregunto a cuántos no habras trabado con tu ciclo infinito, incluído tú mismo, en fin, este es un acercamiento más sano a lo que propones: https://jsfiddle.net/0f6bkbhz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El interprete de javascript **no es multihilo**, por ende, **no es posible modificar el valor de `bandera` mientras se está esperando/ejecutando otra/s sentencias** (en este caso el while), resultando en un loop infinito.

Esto lo puedes visualizar facilmente en el siguiente script:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("STOP!");
}, 1);


for(let i=0; i<200000; i++) {
   console.log('ejecutando '+i);
}
```

Independientemente del intervalo de tiempo que definas en `setTimeout` se terminara **esparando por la operación que dure mas tiempo entre el intervalo definido y la otra operación bloqueante**.

Como se puede ver el fin del intervalo se ejecuta recién luego de 200 mil ejecuciones de `console.log`, **a pesar de haberle indicado 1 milisegundo de delay.**

**¿Cual sería una solución correcta al problema?**

- Puedes utilizar [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) para ejecutar un conjunto de sentencias cada determinado tiempo, en este caso, siempre
- Luego, usar [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) para detener la ejecución de `setInterval` mediante `clearInterval()`

```js
// Ejecuto siempre..
let interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Ejecutando...");
}, 0);

// A los 2 segundos cancelo ejecucion 
setTimeout(function(){ 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    console.log('FIN'); 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

La razón es muy sencilla:

**JavaScript se ejecuta en un solo hilo.**

Por lo tanto el código dentro del `setTimeOut` que espera ser ejecutado es bloqueado por el `while` infinito, en pocas palabras hasta que no se termine la ejecución de ese `while` no se podrá ejecutar el evento, incluso a pesar de ya haber terminado el tiempo (60s).

Por lo tanto `bandera` nunca se setea en `false` y el bucle nunca termina.

**Moraleja:**

Que el `setTimeout` se ejecute de forma **asíncrona** no quiere decir que se ejecute en otro hilo.